# NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

i use xcode 9

```
NSMutableArray *Upcase_Keys = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4,"@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"0"]; 
NSString *str = [Upcase_Keys objectAtIndex:0];
str = @"test";
[Upcase_Keys replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:str];
```

Gets specific data for NSMutableArray

It transforms the value and overwrites the existing index.

However, this code causes a crash.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex Crash

So there should be an error in console. Console will help you 99% of the cases when there is a crash, read it! 
It should be something like `-[NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:] unrecognized selector sent to instance`. That's the important part of your error. `NSArrayI` meaning `NSImmutableArray` (`NSArray` in other words), which is not a `NSMutableArray` which points out that the issue is about the creation of `Upcase_Keys`.

Why then? Because `@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4,"@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"0"];` that's a short hand syntax for `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`. So even if it's declared as a `NSMutableArray`, the object is in fact a `NSArray`.
In fact, if you'd listen to XCode, it should give you this warning:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing `'NSMutableArray *'` with an
>   expression of type `'NSArray *'`

Which concords with everything said before.` Sometimes XCode may be wrong, but try to listen to it.

There are a few possibilities call:

```
NSMutableArray *Upcase_Keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4,"@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"0"]];
NSMutableArray *Upcase_Keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4,"@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"0"]];
NSMutableArray *Upcase_Keys = [@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4,"@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"0"] mutableCopy];
```

And finally, a recommendation use *camelcase*:
Avoid naming your var with an uppercase. Use a lower case for the first letter. I'd say that after the `_` is less problematic, but we tend in iOS to write instead.

`Upcase_Keys` => `upcase_Keys` => `upcaseKeys`

Answer (score 0):

You have defined as immutable object, The syntax will assign NSArray reference not NSMutableArray. You can't update the NSArray.

Try like this,

```
NSMutableArray *Upcase_Keys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4,"@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"0"]];
```